# Sliding line plot (animation)

Tags: matlab

How to animate a line graph while the values change in time using MATLAB? 
I mean, a sliding line from the beginnig of the data till the end.

Comment: How do you want the animation to look like?

Comment: just a 2D plot and an animation which updates the current value but doesnt erase the previous. Which allows the flow completely to be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just execute your plotting method again with the updated values, but first call

```
hold all
```

this keeps the previous plot on display. This isn't animated of course, but maybe this is already enough.

Comment: x = -pi:.1:pi
y = sin(x)

Basically i want to operate plot(x,y) but want to graph it in a sliding manner. I tried hold all but didnt work for this situation. I need something like a "moving snake" on the graph.

Comment: as far as I know, there are no builtin automated solutions for that, but on the FEX there is [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18210)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am trying to handle it with getframe in a loop.